# How to use argument for table name in dynamic SQL

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, dynamic-sql

I am writing a Postgres function to get the number of new records in a table. Here table name is a variable.

```
create or replace function dmt_mas_updates(
    tb_name text,
    days integer)
    returns integer as
$$
declare
    ct integer;
begin
    execute 'select count(*) from $1 where etl_create_dtm > now() - $2 * interval ''1 days'' '
    using tb_name, days into ct;
    return ct;

end;
$$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
```

When I call the function with `select * from dmt_mas_updates('dmt_mas_equip_store_dim',2);`, I got syntax error at `$1`.

If I run the query directly `select count(*) from  dmt_mas_equip_store_dim where etl_create_dtm >= interval '3 days'`, it works correctly.

Why am I getting this error? What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per [the documentation:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN)

> Note that parameter symbols can only be used for data values — if you want to use dynamically determined table or column names, you must insert them into the command string textually.

Use the [`format()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-FORMAT) function:

```
create or replace function dmt_mas_updates(
    tb_name text,
    days integer)
    returns integer as
$$
declare
    ct integer;
begin
    execute format(
        'select count(*) from %I where etl_create_dtm > now() - $1 * interval ''1 days'' ',
        tb_name)
    using days into ct;
    return ct;

end;
$$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```